# How to properly use Yii2 querybuilder insert method?

Tags: yii2, sql-insert, query-builder

I was trying to use the `QueryBuilder` object to generate a properly escaped `INSERT` statement. The database table name is generated using an uploaded file's name and there'd be multiple tables, so using a model here is not really an option.

The code I tried to use was this:

```
                        $params = [
                            "index" => $row["A"],
                            "description" => $row["B"],
                        ];
                        $conn->createCommand(
                            $qb->insert($tableName, [
                                "Index" => ":index",
                                "Description" => ":description",
                            ], $params),
                            $params
                        )->execute();
```

The SQL error message I got was this that the number of parameters did not match the number of tokens.

Answer (score 1):

My primary problem was that the documentation does not properly explain what the `$params` variable should be. I found out that it should be an empty, but initialised array, so basically `$params = [];`.

Also, since the function uses `$params` as a reference, they are already processed by the `QueryBuilder` object and I don't need to escape my values two times.

The final code that worked was this:

```
                        $params = [];
                        $conn->createCommand(
                            $qb->insert($tableName, [
                                "Index" => $row["A"],
                                "Description" => $row["B"],
                            ], $params),
                            $params
                        )->execute();
```

I hope this helps anyone out there sometime.

Answer (score 0):

It is simple as that:

```
$conn->createCommand()->insert($tableName, [
    "Index" => $row["A"],
    "Description" => $row["B"],
])->execute();
```

The yii\db\Command::insert() does the escaping for you. E.g.:

```
$a = "a'b\"";
echo \Yii::$app->db->createCommand()->insert('t', ['a' => $a])->getRawSql() . "\n";
```

returns

```
INSERT INTO `t` (`a`) VALUES ('a\'b\"')
```